# How is Ingress metric averaged?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Metrics page of the Azure storage account can display the number of bytes that were written in to the account (Ingress).

When I select a "sum" of Ingress, with 1-minute granularity, I get about 60GiB per tick, which translates to 1GiB per second.

But, when I switch to "avg" of Ingress, the chart shows around 5MiB per tick. This is 200x smaller than what I would expect to see.

How is the "average" calculated for the Ingress metric, and what is the period of time it is averaging over?